# Actual signature of async_wait() handler

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-bind

I have a two-layer object structure where the contained object has a deadline_timer and the outer object has the handler function, as:

```
class Internal
{
    asio::deadline_timer t;
public:
    void QueueTick(void (*handler)(boost::system::error_code const&))
    {
       t.expires_from_now(posix_time::millisec(250));
       t.async_wait(handler);
    }
};

class ForClients
{
    Internal I;
    void OnTick(boost::system::error_code const&) { /*...*/ }
    void Init()
    {
        I.QueueTick(boost::bind(&cdevXcite::OnTick, this, _1));
    }
};
```

The `QueueTick()` call is failing to compile in MSVS 2008 with "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::_bi::bind_t' to 'void (__cdecl *)(const boost::system::error_code &)'".

If I make the timer member public and make a direct call to `I.t.async_wait()` with the same argument, it succeeds.  Clearly, the handler's signature is more special than what I've used in the `QueueTick` declaration; however, I can't find a symbol that defines it and I don't know how to interpret the metaprogramming going on inside the `basic_deadline_timer<>` template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An asio timer's `async_wait` can be called with any callable type that can be called with a `boost::system::error_code const&` argument. There isn't a single type anywhere that defines it, it just has to be callable with the documented argument type.

The type of your QueueTick parameter is one such callable type, a pointer to a plain ol' non-member function with the right signature:

```
void QueueTick(void (*handler)(boost::system::error_code const&))
```

But the result of `boost::bind` is a class type with an overloaded `operator()` which is not convertible to that function pointer type.

There are a few ways to solve this, but the simplest is probably to follow `async_wait` itself and write QueueTick as a function template, accepting any type:

```
class Internal
{
  asio::deadline_timer t;
public:
  template<WaitHandle>
    void QueueTick(WaitHandle handler)
    {
      t.expires_from_now(posix_time::millisec(250));
      t.async_wait(handler);
    }
};
```

The rest of the code would be unchanged.

If that's not an option (e.g. because QueueTick needs to be virtual) then you could use `boost::function` with can hold any callable object of the right signature:

```
class Internal
{
  asio::deadline_timer t;
public:
  typedef boost::function<void(boost::system::error_code const&)> handler_type;
  void QueueTick(handler_type handler)
    {
      t.expires_from_now(posix_time::millisec(250));
      t.async_wait(handler);
    }
};
```

This will have a small overhead compared to the template version, due to constructing the `boost::function` object.

Comment: Thanks, boost::function is what I was looking for.

Comment: Working with this more, it seems that Boost.ASIO should do the same thing -- use a function<> signature instead of a templated async_wait() method. Agree?

Comment: What do you mean "should do"? If you're saying ASIO would be better if it did that, I disagree. There's no benefit to adding a dependency on `function<>`, the member function template works fine for any callable type, without needing to allocate memory or depend on `function<>` being available.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++11, you can do something like:

```
class Internal
{
    asio::deadline_timer t;

public:
    void QueueTick(const std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&)>& handler)
    {
        t.expires_from_now(posix_time::millisec(250));
        t.async_wait(handler);
    }
};

class ForClients
{
    Internal I;
    void OnTick(const boost::system::error_code& ec) { /*...*/ }
    void Init()
    {
        I.QueueTick([this](const boost::system::error_code& ec) { OnTick(ec); });
    }
};
```